# gnome system monitor in solaris 10

Tags: solaris

is there any gui tools like gnome system monitor in solaris for monitoring processes? or is it possible to get the gnome system monitor binary pkgfor solaris os ?If pls give me the link to package

Answer (score 1):

Here is the correct answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1881065/gnome-system-monitor-for-solaris/1882143#1882143